# How can I initialize 2nd array elements which are 'double data type' as -1 or 0 easily

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

I want to initialize double 2nd array elements as -1 or 0 easily.

In case of integer, we can write like below

```
int cache[100][100];
memset(cache, -1, 100*100*sizeof(int));
```

But In case of double, How can I initialize this 2nd array easily? the best approach that I can handle, but quite ugly,  is below

```
double cache[100][100];
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
   for(int j=0; j<100; j++)
       cache[i][j] = -1;
```

Does anybody know best solution about this?

Comment: Are you sure the integer version does what you expect? `memset` fills a memory area with a consistent byte, not an int. Version 2 is a much clearer indication of what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: version 1 implies two's complement

Comment: I know what you mean. Therefore, 'memset' can fill a memory area -1 or 0. What I want to know is that there is a certain STL that can achieve above goal.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc not sure it is a duplicate as that answer doesn't really address 2D arrays (or if it does I didn't look hard enough ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initializing elements of an array to `0` is simple.

```
double cache[100][100] = {};
```

Initializing them to `-1` is not easy. You'll have to have the entire array written out as:

```
double cache[100][100] = {-1, repeat 10000 times};
```

You can set them to `-1` using:

```
std::fill(cache[0], cache[0]+100*100, -1);
```

Comment: Great!That is what I want to know